# In MVC Scaffolding using EF Crud operation why required primary key for input

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext, ado.net-entity-data-model

I made DB and Attach with Data entity Model in that I have table name Employee and primary key EMPID which autoincrement. And then I am adding Scaffolding Insert Update Delete automatic using entity framework.

So it always shows to enter EMPId also which is primary key and autoincrement too.

```
 public partial class ProductCategory 
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 
    public string ProductName { get; set; } 
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductPrice { get; set; } 
    public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } 
}
```

This is my model class which automatic created by EF –

Comment: Can you show your model? Is EMPID field decorated with KeyAttribute?

Comment: I updated sir the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this attributes on your primary key

```
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int ProductId { get;  set; }
```